# No response from server while publishing to node

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I am trying to get the node (in android and using `asmack` library ) and trying to publish some content over that node , but unfortunately 
when `node = (LeafNode) mgr.getNode(nodeNameTxt.getText().toString());` 
line gets executed i am getting following error

```
 No response from server.: 
at org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.packet.SyncPacketSend.getReply(SyncPacketSend.java:50)
at org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.packet.SyncPacketSend.getReply(SyncPacketSend.java:61)
at org.jivesoftware.smackx.pubsub.PubSubManager.getNode(PubSubManager.java:161)
at com.bcl.NodeManager.publishNode(NodeManager.java:176)
at com.bcl.NodeManager.access$1(NodeManager.java:167)
at com.bcl.NodeManager$2.run(NodeManager.java:101)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Here is my code

```
    PubSubManager mgr = new PubSubManager(xmpp, "pubusb.example.com");
          // Get the node
    LeafNode node;

    try {
            //HERE I AM GETTING THE ERROR
        node = (LeafNode) mgr.getNode(nodeNameTxt.getText().toString());
        node.send(new PayloadItem("test" + System.currentTimeMillis(), 
                   new SimplePayload("book", "pubsub:test:book", "")));
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

even when a following line get executed i am getting the same error

```
createLeaf = mgr.createNode(nodeNameTxt.getText().toString());
```

I really dont know whats happening as i have set `SmackConfiguration.setPacketReplyTimeout(10000);`
and server is running fine with stophe javascript sample also.

Comment: Can anyone help me over this plz

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the "to" address is incorrect and the packet is not being sent to the pubsub service in your server.  Try initializing your pubsub manager like this.

```
PubSubManager mgr = new PubSubManager(xmpp, "pubsub.xmppdomain.com");
```

where xmppdomain.com is of course your actual xmpp domain.

You can run with smack.debugEnabled on (or whatever the android equivalent is) to check the XML being sent, to confirm it is going where it should be.

Comment: i tried to set that parameter too by my own ejabberd server , but unfortunately the result is same , moreover i have also set the debug parameter and above stanza are taken from that only